# How could this procedural JS be made more functional?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Given this function that re-orders an array based on a user setting...

```
function getDayNamesInUserOrder() {

    var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    var weekStartDayIndex = 2; // user has set this to be 2 (Tuesday)

    // remove the first n days from the front of the array...
    var daysSlicedFromStart = dayNames.splice(0, weekStartDayIndex);

    // and stick them onto the end of it.
    var dayNamesInUserOrder = dayNames.concat(daysSlicedFromStart);

    return dayNamesInUserOrder;
}

getDayNamesInUserOrder();
=> ['Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon']
```

How could this be made more functional while using less state and variables?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
function getDayNamesInUserOrder(offset) {
  var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  return [0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(function (i) {
    return dayNames[(i+offset) % 7];
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
function getDayNamesInUserOrder(startIndex) {
    var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dayNames.length; i++) {
        result.push(dayNames[(startIndex + i) % dayNames.length]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ddhagb33/

---

FYI, it seems hard to find a crisp definition of "functional programming".  What I could find is that:

1. Data should be immutable - if you want a modified version of data, you create a new modified copy
2. Functions should be stateless (no side effects that influence future calls to the same function)

This function satisfies both of those (as does your original).  If you have a more specific desire to "be more functional", then please describe exactly what you're after.

Comment: Can you explain the modulo math?

Comment: That's actually less functional and more procedural.

Comment: @BryceHanscomb - taking any `integer % array.length` is a common way to wrap around back to the beginning of an array whenever the index goes off the end without creating any sort of `if/else` clauses.  So, we just start collecting results at the desired index, proceed `dayNames.length` values and wrap around when we get to the end.

Comment: @DanD. - Feel free to offer a more "functional" answer.  I'd like to see what you come up with.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getDayNamesInUserOrder() {
  var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  var weekStartDayIndex = 2; // user has set this to be 2 (Tuesday)

  return dayNames.concat(dayNames).slice(weekStartDayIndex, weekStartDayIndex + 7);
}
```